# Retitling tab labels

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

Context: I tend to use tabs to contain splits of files that are grouped around some purpose (e.g. in a typical MVC framework, I'll have the model/view/controller files for a given part of the app open in splits under the same tab). Since these groups tend to use the same filenames across different parts of my codebases (like `views.py`, or `main.yml`), the tab names are useless - I have to switch through the tabs and examine the file contents or full paths to see what they actually contain.

Is there a way I could either make the tab titles more useful in these situations automatically, or a way to manually change the tab title? I'm flexible in how exactly this would be done since I imagine it's an esoteric need.

Comment: I know that you could write your own custom function for the tab line, but maybe you will find useful using vim-ctrlspace plugin for that?

Comment: `:help setting-tabline` should help

Comment: Actually this is an exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/715928/vim-change-label-for-specific-tab - that question has an answer pointing to a plugin that does exact what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`'tabline'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tabline%27) setting for this. Here's an example adapted from [`:help setting-tabline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#setting%2dtabline):

```
set tabline=%!MyTabLine()

" Set the entire tabline
function! MyTabLine()
    let s = ''
    for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        " select the highlighting
        if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
            let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
            let s .= '%#TabLine#'
        endif

        " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
        let s .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T'

        " the label is made by MyTabLabel()
        let s .= ' %{MyTabLabel(' . (i + 1) . ')} '
    endfor

    " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
    let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'

    " right-align the label to close the current tab page
    if tabpagenr('$') > 1
        let s .= '%=%#TabLine#%999Xclose'
    endif

    return s
endfunction

" Set the label for a single tab
function! MyTabLabel(n)

    " This is run in the scope of the active tab, so t:name
    " won't work.
    let l:tabname = gettabvar(a:n, 'name', '')

    " This variable exists!
    if l:tabname != ''
        return l:tabname
    endif

    " If it's not found fall back to the buffer name
    let buflist = tabpagebuflist(a:n)
    let winnr = tabpagewinnr(a:n)
    let l:bname = bufname(buflist[winnr - 1])

    " Unnamed buffer, scratch buffer, etc. Could be more detailed.
    if l:bname == ''
        let l:bname = '[No Name]'
    endif

    return l:bname
endfunction
```

The key is in the `MyTabLabel()` function. If the tab-local `t:name` variable exists, we use that. Otherwise we default back to the currently active buffer name.

To name the tab label, simple set the `t:name` variable for that tab. For the currently active tab:

```
:let t:name = 'Session one'
```

or for a specific tab nr:

```
:call settabvar(3, 'name', 'Session four')
```