# What is the default 'tabline' function?

Tags: functions

Or at least, where to find it in the [Vim source code](https://github.com/vim/vim)?

Tried to show it with `:set tabline`, but only got an empty string back. The custom function example in [`:h tabline`](https://vimhelp.org/tabpage.txt.html#setting-tabline) is helpful and one that

> resembles the default, **but without** adding a + for a modified buffer or
> truncating the names.

---

###### Why do I need this?

What I'm trying to achieve is pretty much explained in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9881/7706), but can't get into the intricacies of Vimscript at the moment to recreate the default behaviour, so I was planning to

1. get the default function, and
2. tack the above solution onto it.

(If this is not possible, will just have to find the time to learn Vimscript properly..:)

Answer (score 1):

Just like for the status line, the internal routine used to generate the tab line is simply not accessible at runtime so looking for it is an exercise in futility.

The recommended approach, as with the status line, is to *replicate* the default behavior, and then, customize it to your requirement. See the example under `:help setting-tabline`.

That replication and that customization are supposed to happen in the linked answer's `MyTabLine()`.